# How to configure Java logging in application code

Tags: java, javafx, java.util.logging

I would like to configure application logging from within my JavaFX application.
It looks like this.

```
 for (Handler handler : Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers()) {
   handler.setFormatter(new One LineFormatter());
   handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
 }
 Logger.getLogger("").setLevel(Level.FINE);
```

Unfortunately this also changes log level for all packages and I am drowned by messages from, for example, JavaFX package.
How do I differentiate log levels between packages? I have seen examples doing this using a configuration file, but I prefer doing this in code.

Comment: Java is space sensitive!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
Logger.getLogger("").setLevel(Level.FINE);
```

set the packages which you want to change, e.g.

```
Logger.getLogger("javafx").setLevel(Level.FINE);
```

Comment: ahhh,,, think reverse. Thanks,